# running android emulator inside vagrant machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to run an android emulator inside a vagrant machine but i keep getting this error :

```
==> default: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
==> default: Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
==> default: CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing).
```

Before starting the emulator i am installing KVM :

```
==> default: qemu-kvm is already the newest version
```

But I have this error:

```
==> default: INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
==> default: KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

The Vagrant configuration is this :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
   config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant'
   config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.222"
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
   config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "Vagrantinit"
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 1
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
   end
 end
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is your CPU and did you enable virtualization in BIOS? Maybe your processor does not have it, if it's older.

Comment: i would like to enable visualization in BIOS but since it's a vagrant machine used in Jenkins, i could not find a way to do that

Comment: Why do you need to use vagrant for android anyway? As far as I know, android emulator usually uses HAXM and not KVM...

Comment: the situation is that I have tests for a specific app that i need to run in an internal CI, and in order to run these tests i need to setup a ubuntu machine using vagrant in that CI, than within that machine, run an android emulator, than execute tests

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with x86 emulation, apparently it's not supported

instead use armeabi-v7a for android emulator, and it should work